# pip install with python dependencies problem

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, pip

we are installing the pip ( pip 20.1.1 ) as

```
tar -xvzf pip-20.1.1.tar.gz -C /install
cd /install/pip-20.1.1
python setup.py install
```

we get exception as

```
/usr/lib64/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'project_urls'

warning.warn(msg)

Traceback (most recent call last):

File stup.py line 87 in module

python_requires => 2.7, !=3, !=3.1, !=3.2, !=3.3, !=3.4
```

not clear why this exception since we have the installed the following python version

```
python python2 python2.7 python2.7-config python-config python3 python-config
```

setuptool version is:

```
easy_install --version
setuptools 44.1.1 from /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (Python 2.7)
```

Comment: Which Linux distribution are you using? You can usually install pip for Python2.7 via your distro's package manager

Comment: we have upgrade OS RHEL from 7.2 to 7.6

Comment: Try `sudo yum install python2-pip`?

Comment: we not using network its offline machine  ( we are using only the pip pkg pip-20.1.1.tar.gz

Comment: Why do you need pip if the machine is offline? You won't be able to download packages from any indexes

Comment: we download the modules also offline

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240197/discussion-between-jessica-and-iain-shelvington).